# How to group consecutive letters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, compression

For example: string = aaaacccc, then I need the output to be 4a4c. Is there a way to do this without using any advanced methods, such as libraries or functions?

Also, if someone knows how to do the reverse: turning "4a4c: into aaaacccc, that would be great to know.

Comment: What did you try? What issues have you ran into?

Comment: So far, all I have done is make sure that the string only contains letters by doing: if string.isalpha() == true:

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work in one iteration

Keep two temp variable one for current character, another for count of that character and one variable for the result.

Just iterate through the string and keep increasing the count if it matches with the previous one.

If it doesn't then update the result with count and value of character and update the character and count.

At last add the last character and the count to the result. Done!

```
input_str = "aaaacccc"
if input_str.isalpha():
  current_str = input_str[0]
  count = 0
  final_string = ""
  for i in input_str:
    if i==current_str:
      count+=1
    else:
      final_string+=str(count)+current_str
      current_str = i
      count = 1
  final_string+=str(count)+current_str

  print (final_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution and I included even a patchwork reverse operation like you mentioned in your post. Both run in O(n) and are fairly simple to understand. The encode is basically identical one posted by Akanasha, he was just a bit faster in posting his answer while i was writing the decode().

```
def encode(x):
    if not x.isalpha():
        raise ValueError()
    output = ""
    current_l = x[0]
    counter = 0
    for pos in x:
        if current_l != pos:
            output += str(counter) + current_l
            counter = 1
            current_l = pos
        else:
            counter += 1

    return output + str(counter) + current_l


def decode(x):
    output = ""
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if x[i].isnumeric():
            n = i + 1
            while x[n].isnumeric():
                n += 1
            output += int(x[i:n])*x[n]
            i = n
        i += 1
    return output


test = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasasggggggbbbbdd"
test1 = encode(test)
print(test1)

test2 = decode(test1)
print(test2)

print(test == test2)
```

Answer (score -2):

yes, you do not need any libraries:

```
list1 = list("aaaacccc")
letters = []
for i in list1:
    if i not in letters:
        letters.append(i)
string = ""
for i in letters:
    string += str(list1.count(i))
    string+=str(i)
print(string)
```

Basically, it loops through the list, finds the unique letters and then prints the count with the letter itself. Reversing would be the same function, just print the amount.

Comment: Can you make it run in O(n) instead of O(n^2)?

Comment: @DeepSpace It's not O(n^2) it is O(2n)

Comment: @Akansha No, its worse case is O(n^2), since `list.count` is O(n)